# How to securely access AWS RDS data from Google App Engine running PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, amazon-rds, serverless

I have this setup currently.

My front end runs on Google App Engine ( GAE ) on PHP. I use PDO to connect to an open AWS RDS MYSLQ 8.

I can not move the data out of the AWS RDS instance.

I have been requested to make the RDS secure and not allow open in coming ports like 0.0.0.0/0 in the AWS security group.

I want to know if there is a serverless way to achieve this type of connection without setting up a EC proxy or an Google Compute Engine server.

I am not able to find a solution and all known solution points to setting up a proxy.

Any one have any thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell something without any codes and errors stacks etc. But I have some thoughts.

If you are thinking of "serverless" solution. "serverless" does not mean that there is no server, but it means that there is no need to care about sever which is being maintained by some service provider (like GAE or other). So practically there is no 100% serverless solution, but it's just covered behind provider logic.

The main question is that you cannot connect to RDS. This should be possible form local machine. So you should be able to develop something that is working on your local machine and than for sure you are able to deploy the same logic to App Engine.

If above is not possible, you should consider GCP cloud SQL or serverless.